# How to name an object in DAO package that has the same name in the model?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

For example, in the model I have the object: Object (the table in the database is object), then the DAO class is ObjectDAO, but I have a base class named ObjectDAO too, which the another DAO classes extends, what name do you recommend to set?

I believe the name maybe BaseDAO

Answer (score 0):

So, i really think that you may rename you entity class to another name to solve this conflict. But if you really need this, you can extend like this:

```
package entity;
public class BaseDAO{}// (your entity)

package dao;
public abstract BaseDAO<E extends Object>  //(Your base dao)
```

Then in the dao for the entity BaseDAO:

```
package whatever; // not into the dao package ofcourse.
public class BaseDAO extends dao.BaseDAO<entity.BaseDAO> {} //
```

You need to inform the entire package name for all classes.